# Why does writing from Spark to Vertica DB take longer than writing from Spark to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, vertica

Ultimately, I want to grab data from a Vertica DB into Spark, train a machine learning model, make predictions, and store these predictions into another Vertica DB.

Current issue is identifying the bottleneck in the last part of the flow: storing values in Vertica DB from Spark. It takes about 38 minutes to store 63k rows of data in a Vertica DB. In comparison, when I transfer that same data from Spark to **MySQL database**, it takes **10 seconds**.

I don't know why the difference is so huge.

I have classes called VerticaContext and MySQLContext for Vertica and MySQL connections respectively. Both classes use the [SQLContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#SQLContext(org.apache.spark.SparkContext)) to read entries using the jdbc format.

```
df = self._sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url=self._jdbcURL, dbtable=subquery).load()
```

And write using jdbc.

```
df.write.jdbc(self._jdbcURL, table_name, save_mode)
```

There's no difference between the two classes aside from writing to a different target database. I'm confused as to why there's a huge difference in the time it takes to save tables. Is it because of the inherent difference in hardware between the two different databases?

Comment: Perhaps it might be because Vertica is a columnar database?

Comment: Is Spark doing single INSERT's ?

Comment: There's too few details in your question. It's possible that your Vertica database is not optimized for trickle inserts that you are performing via JDBC. You will need to talk to your DBA.

Comment: On the application side you could try streaming inserts, as explained [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientJDBC/BatchInsertsUsingJDBCPreparedStatements.htm)

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks for the link. Do you know if there's a python equivalent to this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "python equivalent"; since you're using JDBC setting JDBC properties should present little problem, no?

Comment: @mustaccio the link you provided has code written in java.

Referring to the comment you both made about inserts, it does look like I'm performing inserts through JDBC due to the write time into Vertica DB. From this link: http://vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?t=124 it looks like INSERTS are very time consuming and I need to look for a COPY alternative.

Comment: Do any of you know if there's a way to modify the JDBC connection such that Vertica sees the write as a COPY?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an alternative solution. Before I dive in, I'll explain what I found and why I think saves to Vertica DB are slow.

- Vertica log (search for the file "vertica.log" on your Vertica machine) contains all the recent logs related to reads/writes from and to Vertica DBs. After running the write command, I found out that this is essentially creating INSERT statements into the Vertica DB.
- INSERT statements (without the "DIRECT" directive) are slow because they are written into the WOS (RAM) instead of ROS (disk). I don't know the exact details as to why that's the case. The writes were issuing individual INSERT statements
- Slow inserts are a known issue. I had trouble finding this information, but I finally found a few links that support that. I'm placing them here for posterity: http://www.vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?t=267, http://vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?t=124

My solution:

There is [documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientJDBC/BulkLoadingUsingTheCOPYStatement.htm) that says the COPY command (with a "DIRECT" keyword) is the most efficient way of loading large amounts of data to the database. Since I was looking for a python solution, I used Uber's vertica-python [package](https://github.com/uber/vertica-python) which allowed me to establish a connection with the Vertica DB and send Vertica commands to execute.

I want to exploit the efficiency of the COPY command, but the data lives somewhere outside of the Vertica cluster. I need to send the data from my Spark cluster to Vertica DB. Fortunately, there's a way to do that from HDFS (see [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/HadoopIntegrationGuide/HDFSConnector/LoadingDataFromHDFS.htm)). I settled on converting the dataframe to a csv file and saving that on HDFS. Then I sent the COPY command to the  Vertica DB to grab the file from HDFS.

My code is below (assuming I have a variable that stores the pyspark dataframe already. Let's call that 'df'):

```
    import vertica_python as VertPy

    df.toPandas().to_csv(hdfs_table_absolute_filepath, header=False, index=False)
    conn_info = {
        'host': ['your-host-here']
        'port': [port #],
        'user': ['username'],
        'password': ['password'],
        'database': ['database']
    }

    conn = VertPy.connect(**conn_info)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    copy_command = create_copy_command(table_name, hdfs_table_relative_filepath)
    cursor.execute(copy_command)

    def create_copy_command(table_name, table_filepath):
        copy_command = "COPY " + table_name + " SOURCE Hdfs(url='http://hadoop:50070/webhdfs/v1" + table_filepath + "', username='root') DELIMITER ',' DIRECT ABORT ON ERROR"
        return copy_command
```

Comment: The issue is that it is doing multiple `insert...values` which is very inefficient in Vertica.  The `DIRECT` you'll want to be careful with if you are doing lots of transactions to the same table in a short time as each one will create a ROS container.  Using the COPY is correct, though.   Also, if your data is in your dataframe, you could use `vertica_python`'s copy method and stream the data in that way instead of using the `SOURCE`... you'd use `FROM STDIN`.